# Como alternar e mostrar automaticamente entre as janelas MDI filhas em um MDI pai no c# visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, mdi

Tenho uma aplicação que quando carrega o form principal (pai), ele cria automaticamente dois forms filhos e mostram maximizados, utilizo o seguinte codigo no form Pai para criar os dois forms:

```
       for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            frmSinotico sin = new frmSinotico(Par1, i+Par2);
            sin.MdiParent = this;
            sin.Show();
        }
```

Porém tenho que colocar *no form Principal (pai)* um timer que alterne a exibição desses dois formularios. Utilizei o FormCollecion no timer para carregar os formularios abertos e para ver se existem.

```
        FormCollection formAbertos = Application.OpenForms;
        foreach (Form frms in formAbertos)
        {
            string nome = frms.Text ;
            var formAb = Application.OpenForms[nome];
        }
        Application.OpenForms[formAb ].Focus();
```

Porem dá erro quando tento mostrar o focus no nome do formulario que retorna.

Tem algum outro modo para fazer isso?

Answer (score 0):

Qual erro está aparecendo? Você declarou a variável dentro da iteração `foreach`, e está tentando acessa-la fora.

Outra coisa, você garante que o `Text` do form será exatamente o mesmo que o `Nome` do Form? Acredito que não seria uma boa prática utilizar dessa maneira.

O que você poderia tentar é dar o focus dentro da iteração mesmo, apenas verifica se o form é diferente do form pai, e se ela ja está com o focus.

```
FormCollection formAbertos = Application.OpenForms;
foreach (Form frms in formAbertos)
{
     //ignora se o form for o Pai
     if(frms is FormPai)
     {
         continue;
     }
     
     //verifica se ele ja está com o focus
     if (!frms.Focused)
     {
         frms.Focus();
         //interrompe
         break;
     }
}
```